# Is there any way to send data to asp.net mvc controller httppost action method from Excel using VBA

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel, post, vba

My controller is:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Updtdb(string longStr)
{
//some code here!
}
```

I am trying to send data to my website from excel. 
Here is what i have tried so far.

```
Sub XMLPost()
Dim xmlhttp, longStr As String

    With ActiveSheet
        longStr = "x=" & generateData
    End With

    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("microsoft.xmlhttp")

    With xmlhttp
        .Open "POST", " http://localhost:54188/DashBoard/Updtdb", False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .send longStr
    End With
End Sub

Function generateData()
    Dim longString As String, range As range

    Set range = Sayfa8.range("SummaryTable")

    For Each cell In range.Cells
        longString = longString + CStr(cell.Value) + ";"
    Next cell

    generateData = longString
End Function
```

When i run Sub XML Post() it works but does not invoke the action method. I am not sure how to achieve it or is it even achievable. Any help?

Comment: Can you show the Route for your Controller ?

Comment: app.UseMvc(routes =>
                {
                    routes.MapRoute(
                        name: "default",
                        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                });

Comment: Have you tried to change the signature of your controller method from `[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Updtdb(string longStr)
{
//some code here!
}` to `[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Updtdb(ModelX model)
{
//some code here!
}` where `class ModelX{ public string x{get;set;}}`

Comment: @alex I tried as you said but stil no results.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solotion finally. My project is using asp.net authentication. DashBoardController is only avilable for authenticated users. I have added a data annotation to my action controller. Now everything works fine.

> [AllowAnonymous]

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Updtdb(string x)
{
    return Content("a");
}
```